# jQuery: highlight TDs with same value by click on another TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, background-color

I have a large HTML table with `onclick` events on each `td` (with the class `myClass`).

Is there a way to make it so that by clicking on a TD I change the background colour for all `td`s with the same value, or to highlight them in any other way?

What I am looking for is a quick way to show `td`s with the same value without the need to filter the table.

**Example TRs:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="myClass">Value 1</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 5</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 3</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 1</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="myClass">Value 3</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 2</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 1</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 5</td>
        <td class="myClass">Value 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: What have you tried? What you mean by 'filter' the table? To get behaviour you wish, you have for sure to filter the table elements is some way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make it so that whenever you click on a `td`, it will highlight all the `td`s with the same text yellow.

```
$("td").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  $("td")
   .css("background-color", "")
   .filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() === value;
   })
  .css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

You can see this in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvC5d/).

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the quick help, I will accept when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straight up jquery answer that is brute force but I think goes along the lines of what you want

```
$('.myClass').on('click',function(choice){
   var choiceText = $(choice).text();
   $('.myClass').each(function(index, element){
       if($(element).text() === choiceText){
           //do whatever you need
       }

    });
});
```

Comment: peter olsons answer is better

Comment: Thanks anyways - fair play. :)